# Where is the documentation for the internals of Qt and the design patterns used for building it

Tags: qt

Please point the docs for understanding the internals of Qt such as the design of the QObject class, The patterns choosen for the Qt classes. The reason for using QVariant class, e.t.c. Although Qt comes with very good documentation and examples, they mostly explain how to use them not why it is being done that way.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such docs. I don't think they exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a blog entry that at least explains the use of private classes and d-pointers in Qt.
[Qt-Howto](http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

I can't begin to answer this authoritatively, but some good resources are the description of the Qt [Object Model](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/object.html) and the [QObject class reference](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qobject.html#details), and the [first half of this document](http://www.ntcore.com/files/qtrev.htm) for demystifying some of the Qt internals like signals and slots. Some of the design justifications are [discussed here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/templates.html) - why they use syntactic sugar, code generators etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the documentation offline, e.g. with QtAssistant or with the help menu integrated in QtCreator, you must download it. Either you install QtCreator with the installer from (qt-project)[http://www.qt-project.org) or you install from a repository of your distribution (if you use linux).

The second option has a little problem. Ubuntu doesn't come with a complete Qt5 documentation. So you can download the necessary .qch (Qt-help-files) from my [Mega account](https://mega.co.nz/#F!IEQViZBD!IH66QnC6nus5tKn7Sh7Usw)

Answer (score -1):

"[Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt" 
book very useful](https://qt-project.org/books/view/introduction-to-design-patterns-in-c-with-qt)